# Please help me get through this unexpected output

Tags: c++, linked-list

This is my sample C++ code for a linked list . This is not actually a linked list but just a dummy program. I get unexpected output for this program.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct list{
int data;
list *next;
};

void setData(list ob){
    int d;
    cout<<"enter data"<<endl;
    cin>>d;
    ob.data=d;
}

void getData(list ob){
    cout<<"Data is :"<<ob.data<<endl;
}


int main(){
list node1,node2,node3;
setData(node1);
setData(node2);
setData(node2);
getData(node1);
getData(node2);
getData(node3);

    return 0;

}
```

My input for the code was 2,3 and 4. The unexpected output that I get is -

```
enter data
2
enter data
3
enter data
4
Data is :2293540
Data is :4201920
Data is :2293608
```

**Edit**

```
struct list{
 char data; list next; 
} 
void main(){
 list *start,node1,node2; 
//I got stuck on the below two lines 
start=(struct list)malloc(sizeof(list)); //Dynamic allocation of memory of size list whose address is stored in start
 start=&node1; // start holds the address of node1 which is not dynamically allocated .
```

I don't understand why is *start given a dynamic address if the second statement overrides it by giving it the memory address of node1 which is in the stack(atlest what I understood).

Comment: You can initialize the data variable in struct constructor 'list():data(0)' as a default value

Comment: @coryKramer Sir I didn't ask any  question. I just commented here.

Comment: @Shivamaggarwal Please [read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). Stack Overflow is made to ask **small, single, specific questions** It is not a forum, so it is not meant for follow-up question one after another. If you original question is answered, which it was since you selected an answer below, please ask a **new** question. I don't know how I can be more clear. Your **new** question is "why isn't this block of code working?", which is **different** than your original question.

Comment: Sorry Cory. I am a newbie here. Wasn't aware about such rules. Will take care from now on .

Comment: @CoryKramer I  am **not the person** asked this question. it is Shivam aggarwal.  Please check this.

Comment: @SatishChalasani My mistake! I apoligize I didn't read carefully once the `@` suggested after I started typing "S..."

Comment: @CoryKramer or Satish can u please answer my previous question. Its kinda urgent . please

Comment: @Shivamaggarwal No I will not, since you refuse to follow the guidelines of the site I am done helping you. If you post a new question, I would be glad to answer your question there.

Comment: Sorry to say but I am a newbie here and wasn't aware of such guidelines and rules. Definately gonna take care next time .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are passing your linked list by value. To change this, pass by reference.

```
void setData(list& ob){
    int d;
    cout<<"enter data"<<endl;
    cin>>d;
    ob.data=d;
```

When you pass by value, C++ makes a **copy** of whatever you pass in. So when you are calling `getData`, you pass in a copy of a list that has no data in it, so garbage is getting printed.

Comment: struct list{ char data; list next; } void main(){ list *start,node1,node2; //I got stuck on the below two lines start=(struct list)malloc(sizeof(list)); //Dynamic allocation of memory of size list whose address is stored in start start=&node1; // start holds the address of node1 which is not dynamically allocated . I don't understand why is *start given a dynamic address if the second statement overrides it by giving it the memory address of node1 which is in the stack(atlest what I understood).

Comment: You are correct the second statement overrides the dynamically allocated address. What is your question?

Comment: I wanted to ask what is the use of 1st statement then ?

Comment: @Shivamaggarwal The first statement is useless. If you have more questions, I would recommend you to start a new question because you already accepted answer to the first question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass in your `list` by reference

```
void setData(list& ob){
    int d;
    cout<<"enter data"<<endl;
    cin>>d;
    ob.data=d;
}
```

You are currently passing in `ob` by *value*, so although you are indeed setting the `data` attribute correctly, you are doing so to the *function-local copy* of `ob`, not the original `list` that you passed into the function.

Comment: struct list{
    char data;
    list *next;
    }
    void main(){
    list *start,node1,node2;
    //I got stuck on the below two lines
    start=(struct list*)malloc(sizeof(list));     //Dynamic allocation of memory of size list whose address is stored in start
    start=&node1;       // start holds the address of node1 which is not dynamically allocated . 

I don't understand why is *start given a dynamic address if the second statement overrides it by giving it the memory address of node1 which is in the stack(atlest what I understood).

Comment: @Shivamaggarwal When you post code in the comment section, all formatting is lost so it is hard to read. If this is part of your original question, please **edit** your above question with this code. Otherwise, if this is a **new** question, please create a new question.

Comment: ok bro I am editing the question. (Newbie here :))Please hold on.